# Markers on a map with CSS and javascript

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I'm making a very simple page which needs to do the following:

There will be a map, which is a background image in a div, and there will be some clickable images distributed on the map (each within a div of its own). The images, when clicked, should make some markers on the map appear or disappear, to indicate positions where that can be found on the map.

It's not supposed to be fancy, it's just supposed to work and be doable quickly (I'm inexperienced and don't have much time). What would you suggest?

I tried to find a way to do it with just css, but the best I can do is a very raw and impractical way of doing it, nothing simple and elegant. I'd like to avoid using any libraries, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do Something Like This

```
document.getElementById('a1').addEventListener('click', toggle);
function toggle(a){
document.getElementById("i1").style.display='block';
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById("i1").style.display='none';
},500);
}
```

Fiddle:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYy4m/)